# Confusing info from /proc/cpuinfo: CPU Frequency:

Tags: cpu-architecture

I ran a 'cat /proc/cpuinfo' on a node I'm using and obtained the following:

```
processor       : 13
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6           
model           : 62          
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz
stepping        : 4                                        
cpu MHz         : 1200.000                                 
cache size      : 25600 KB                                 
physical id     : 1                                        
siblings        : 10                                       
core id         : 3                                        
cpu cores       : 10                                       
apicid          : 38                                       
initial apicid  : 38                                       
fpu             : yes                                      
fpu_exception   : yes                                      
cpuid level     : 13                                       
wp              : yes                                      
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits
```

Why is "cpu MHz :1200", while the model name says it runs at 2.8Ghz?

Comment: You have frequency scaling enabled. Many modern CPUs (at least of the x86/x86_64 families) can run at lower speeds to reduce power consumption when they're not busy doing stuff. The speed will be increased when there is demand for it.

Comment: Looks like a ServerFault or SuperUser question, not StackOverflow?

Comment: Dude who cares?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have frequency scaling enabled. Many modern CPUs (at least of the x86/x86_64 families) can run at lower speeds to reduce power consumption when they're not busy doing stuff. The speed will be increased when there is demand for it.